# Android/Java - Communication from classes return java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, class, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I have created in an Android project the **main class** that extend the **activity**, and another one that extend the main class. I want to use in the main class a method declared in the second class. But i am receiving always a `nullpointerexception`. I put here the two simple classes.
The main class:

```
package com.example.androidserverapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class AndroidServer extends Activity {

  public ImageView main_image;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_server);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
    utilities.initialize();
  }


}
```

The second class:

```
package com.example.androidserverapp;

import android.widget.ImageView;; 

public class Utilities extends AndroidServer{

  public ImageView main_image;

  public void initialize(){
      main_image.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
      main_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
  }

}
```

I saw that the error is referring to the line main_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image); but i'm not understanding what i'm doing wrong. Any help?
Here there is the log cat:

```
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidserverapp/com.example.androidserverapp.AndroidServer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1870)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at com.example.androidserverapp.Utilities.initialize(Utilities.java:8)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at com.example.androidserverapp.AndroidServer.onCreate(AndroidServer.java:20)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is crashing is that you create object of class `Utilities` which extends `AndroidServer` but `onCreate()` method is not called because it is just new java object and activity is not started. So in `initialize()` method you are finding view but you can't do that until you start that activity. Hope you understand what I mean.

EDIT: so you don't need to extend Activity in Utilities class and you can make something like this:

```
public class Utilities {

   public void initialize(View mainHolder){
      ImageView imageView = mainHolder.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
   }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   View contentView = infler.inflate(R.layout.activity_android_server, null);
   setContentView(contentView);
   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

   Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
   utilities.initialize(contentView);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So has more sense put the call to the utilities method in the onResume() method of the activity? Seems that is isn't working too...

Comment: Like I see now, your code is absolutely weird and I really don't understand what you want to achieve, because I overlooked in line main_image.findViewById(R.id.main_image); that you are finding view in ImageView. And main_image is always null.

Comment: the code is simple because i'm only try to learn how call methods from other classes. I have add this line now: main_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3); I want show the image3 object (is a simple .jpg image) in the main view, but i want do it from another class and after call only the method in the main activity.

Comment: I edited my answer. You really should learn some java and android basics using some tutorials etc.

Comment: Thanks it is working, and yes i'm learning, studying and trying.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main_image` is null, you need to declare your imageView in the same class where you declare     `setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_server);`

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1870) 07-12 11:35:04.473: E/AndroidRuntime(14954): at com.example.androidserverapp.Utilities.initialize(Utilities.java:8) 07-12 11:35:04.473:

Comment: I have declared it now, but seems that isn't working. I have updated the code on my question. Thanks